# Monitor disk I/O with zabbix

Tags: centos, monitoring, zabbix

I'm running both zabbix 5.0.30 and zabbix agent 5.0.30 on Centos 7

In Centos 7 server, I executed this command

```
[root@STG-front default]# iostat -d sda
Linux 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64 (STG-front)     01/09/2023  _x86_64_    (1 CPU)

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               0.27         0.60         2.92    1099613    5370225
```

I want to monitor the tps, kB_read/s, kB_wrtn/s, so how can I do it with "Create Items" option in zabbix.

NOTE: I read the "vfs.dev.read" and "vfs.dev.write" on the manual guide but I want to monitor "tps" additionally.

Could someone help me with this case. Thank you in advance.